# Como filtrar acentos en un selectCheckboxMenu de primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, filtro

tengo problema al usar el filtro del selectCheckboxMenu, ya que no filtra los acentos por ejemplo tengo esta lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al filtrar por ejemplo la letra “a”, solo me filtra ese carácter y no el acentuado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe cómo hacer para que me aparezcan ambos caracteres al poner con acento o sin él.

```html
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="menu" value="#{ClassBean.selectedItems}" label="Items" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
   <f:selectItems value="#{ClassBean.items}"/>                
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

---

Creo que no me dí a entender, lo que pasa es que cuando filtro no filtra las palabras con acentos, por ejemplo tengo las palabras:

Círculo
Circulo
Circuló

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando agrego al filtro "cir", me discrimina la primer palabra que comienza con acento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero ver si hay forma de que me tome en cuenta los acentos.

Comment: Pruebalo con palabras a mi si me funciona así como lo tienes

Comment: Aqui hablan de una solución: [Foro](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=47244#p146659). Debes crear una funcion con el atributo: `filterFunction` y ahi tratar la búsqueda.

Answer (score 2):

Para personalizar el filtro, debe definir el atributo **filterMatchMode** como "custom" y utilizar el atributo **filterFunction**="miFiltro" donde se define la función javascript que se usa en la busqueda del filtro, como se explica en la [documentación de Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) (451).

En este caso, personalizo el filtro para ignorar los acentos y los caracteres especiales que están **contenidos** (igual que hace el atributo filterMatchMode="contains").

file.xhtml

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu filter="true" filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction="contains" value="#{controllerBean.id}">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{controllerBean.list}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

file.js

```
function contains(itemLabel, filterValue) {

    return itemLabel.includes(filterValue) || specialCharacters(itemLabel).includes(filterValue);

}

function specialCharacters(input){

           var c=input.toLowerCase();
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'),"");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'),"a");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'),"ae");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'),"c");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'),"e");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'),"i");                           
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'),"o");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'),"oe");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'),"u");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'),"y");
           return c;
}
```

De esta manera se realizará la búsqueda con o sin acento.

La publicación original a esta cuestión la publiqué en el foro de Stackoverflow en inglés, se puede consultar aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514786/filter-custom-in-selectonelistbox-or-selectonemenu-to-ignore-accents-or-special/52514787#52514787

Esta solución vale para cualquier componente de primefaces similar que use filtro de búsqueda, por ejemplo un selectCheckboxMenu, selectOneListbox o selectOneMenu